# Selenium IDE - JQuery onclick handler not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium

I am trying to test a page using the FF Selenium IDE plugin.

There is a menu structure like the following..

```
<ul class="parent">
   <li class="child"><span><a href="something.html">link text</a></span></li>
   <li class="child"><span><a href="somethingelse.html">other text</a></span></li>
<ul>
```

The li elements have a hover event bound to them.  Those hover events register a click event on the actual link tag. (I have stripped out some of the JavaScript for simplification)

```
  var menu = $('ul.parent');

  $("> li.child", menu).hover(function () {

    $(this).find('> a').click(function () {             
      $(this).parent().addClass('active-trail');
      return false;
    });
  }, function() {});
```

If using Selenium I click one of these links then I would expect the handler to be called.  It isn't and the click is simply executed (and the link followed, instead of false being returned).

I have tried (after reading other answers) mouseUp and mouseDown.  I have also tried using fireEvent to firstly hover over the li (to activate the hover event) and then another fireEvent to click the anchor.. but that didn't work either.

So any help would be most appreciated.  Just a basic demonstration of using Selenium to trigger a jquery supplied click handler would probably be enough to see me right!

Thanks,
Patrick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right  with `fireEvent()`, are you sure you were using it right?

If you want to fire the `onClick` handler you would do `fireEvent(locator, "click")` not `fireEvent(locator, "onClick")`.

You probably are doing this right if you are using selenium IDE to generate the scripts.

Selenium is a bit dodgey in this area, I have had many similar problems.

Comment: Yup, certainly using "hover" and "click" as the handlers.  Good to know I'm looking in the right area!

Comment: It may be something to do with Selenium not waiting for the hover to execute before it tries clicking, try adding a wait in between the two commands.

Comment: I tried using the pause but it didn't make a difference.  Interestingly, if I load the page, move my mouse over the element (effectively manually triggering the hover), and then run a click event - then the menu does appear.

Comment: Ah, my mistake - it ended up that I needed to use the mouseOver event first - then I was able to call the click and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using xpath i.e.

selenium.Click("xpath=/descendant::li[contains(.,"something")][2]/x:a")